# How to prevent a css pseudo element from keeping css from the main element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a weird issue where I want to add curly braces before and after an element using css. Since the curly braces don't really exist in the html, I am using css pseudo elements to add the curly braces before and after. My problem is that the pseudo elements are taking the css style from the main css selector. I don't want the curly braces to have underlines, strike-throughs, blue color, etc. How can I prevent this?

Here is a sample of what is going wrong:

```css
amdstyle[type="6"]{
 margin-left: .5em;
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: blue;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:before{
 content:"{";
 text-decoration: none !important; /* Doesn't help */
 border-bottom: none !important; /* Doesn't help */
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:after{
 content:"}";
}
```

```html
<amdstyle type=6>Here is my element</amdstyle>
```

I thought it would be ok to add `text-decoration: none` and `border-bottom: none` to the before and after pseudo elements, but this does not work, they always take the styling of the regular element. Adding `!important` to my styles doesn't help either. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `absolute` position on pseudo-elements.

```css
amdstyle[type="6"] {
  margin-left: .5em;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:before {
  content:"{ ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:after {
  content: " }";
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<amdstyle type=6>Here is my element</amdstyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're actually applying the styles to the same element's pseudo class, you can't really undo the styles without altering the element. However, you can fake it as follows:

```css
amdstyle[type="6"]{
 margin-left: .5em;
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: blue;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
position: relative;
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:before{
 content:"{";
position: absolute;
left: -7px;
 text-decoration: none !important; /* Doesn't help */
 border-bottom: none !important; /* Doesn't help */
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:after{
 content:"}";
position: absolute;
right: -7px;
}
```

```html
<amdstyle type=6>Here is my element</amdstyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using absolute positioning I would go for an additional `<span>` inside of the `<amdstyle>`. This is more responsive as every browser renders text differently and you can't know how many pixels the char takes. In addition, the margin-left will be applied to the left of the brace (not  to the *H* of *Here*).

```css
amdstyle[type="6"] span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:before {
  content:"{";
  margin-left: .5em;
}

amdstyle[type="6"]:after {
  content: "}";
}
```

```html
<amdstyle type=6><span>Here is my element</span></amdstyle>
```

Comment: I can't use this idea in my scenario, but I like the idea.